# MySQL DatabaseError: 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string English mixed with Chinese characters when loading file

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am facing the invalid utf8mb4 character string error when I try to do load data.
The field "descr" can contain Chinese and English characters, as well as all sorts of special characters

I run this from Python using a connector to load data from a csv file

```
CREATE TABLE testTB
(
bunch of columns...,
descr varchar(60)
) 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

LOAD DATA LOCAL FILE 'file_pathname.csv'
INTO TABLE testTB
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(
a bunch of columns...,
descr
);
```

And it gives me the invalid string error.

Then I try to create a smaller version and create my own csv of only 2 columns (amt, descr)

```
CREATE TABLE chincurrent
(
amt float,
descr varchar(60)
)
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'pathname to simpler csv'
INTO TABLE chincurrent
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(
amt,
descr
)
```

Which works fine and I can see the characters in MySQL Workbench.

Why it does not work on my production csv?

I have checked the encodings of the production csv and my own simpler csv are the same i.e. both `cp950`

I also tried copying the entry of descr that caused the error into the simpler csv and it could be inserted just fine.

FYI, the descr invalid string is pointing to `|*45011...N (山竹)|`, the error shows
`Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '|*45011...N ('` so I guess it originates from the Chinese characters.

I have also tried doing things suggested in similar posts like SET NAMES, SET to latin1 (works but would not show the Chinese characters) but to no avail.

Edit:

- I have also tried testing with a csv of all columns in the production csv and it works.
- Tested copying the entire production csv and pasting into the test csv, and it works.

Comment: You must set the encoding of that column to cp950, it's utf8mb4 by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support cp950. You'll need to store it as binary in the db and deal with encoding/decoding in code.

Comment: @MichaelRuth But how does it explain that it works for my test csv, which is also in cp950? I inspect chincurrent table and the character sets for the Descr column is also utf8mb4.

Comment: Could be coincidence that the two rows you chose have characters whose encoding overlaps cp950. Without actual data, it's difficult to say.

Comment: @MichaelRuth  I chose the rows above and below the erroneous row and including the erroneous row for my test csv though

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to me not converting the csv files properly to `utf-8` encoding before feeding into MySQL.

The method I used to check the encoding was

```
with open(pathname) as f:
  print(f)
```

This method returns cp950 to me even if I change the encoding using the manual "save as" method. Likely the with open just uses the locale encoding on my system, which happens to be cp950 (and cp1250 for most US people).

The encoding of the production csv file is in ANSI, which can be obtained by `locale.getpreferrendencoding()`.

To properly insert a csv file of non-utf8 encoding into MySQL by changing the csv file:

```
def to_utf(pathname):

  with open(pathname, 'r', encoding=src_encoding) as f:
    text = f.read()

  with open(pathname, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Replace `src_encoding` with the encoding of the file to be converted.
If you are converting from ANSI, then you can do
`src_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` and remember to `import locale`.

Call this function on the data file before loading data into MySQL.

Thanks to Michael Ruth for the help.